# How to define a function in scope root in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a simple function that it makes a ajax request to get some zipcode information.   The function "GetAddressByZipCode()" is defined in a controller called *"ProposalController"* and it works fine.

Now, i need to put the same function in another controller, in this case "ContactController".  How can i define this function in scope root? 
It needs to be able to use in any others controllers.

See the code below:

```
 myApp.controller('ProposalController', ['$scope',  '$http', function ($scope,  $http){
 function GetAddressByZipCode(zipcode) {

    $http.get('api/cep/consulta/' + zipcode)
         .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             if (data != null) {
                 $scope.address = data.address;
                 $scope.borough = data.borough.description;
                 $scope.city = data.city.description;
                 $scope.state = data.city.state.description;
             }
         })
         .error(function (data) {
             console.log("Error!");
         });
}}

 myApp.controller('ContactController', ['$scope',  '$http', function ($scope,  $http){
     /*I need to invoke the GetAddressByZipCode(zipcode) here*/
  }
```

Comment: Make the function a `Service`. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#!/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `services` folder and a `controllers` folder to isolate responsibilities.

Each service must be a file, like this `categories.js`

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc service
 * @name spawesomeApp.Categories
 * @description
 * # Categories
 * Factory in the spawesomeApp.
 */
 angular.module('spawesomeApp')
 .factory('Categories', function ($http, appConfig) {

    var urlBase = appConfig.API_URL() + '/Category';
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.getCategories = function () {
      return $http.get(urlBase);
    };

    dataFactory.getCategory = function (id) {
      if(id == null)
        throw 'Id não informado';
      return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + id);
    };

    dataFactory.getCategoryBySlug = function(slug){
      if(slug == null)
        throw 'Slug não informado';
      return $http.get(urlBase + '/Slug/' + slug);
    };

    dataFactory.insertCategory = function (category) {
      if(category == null)
        throw 'category não informada';
      return $http.post(urlBase, category);
    };

    dataFactory.updateCategory = function (category) {
      if(category == null)
        throw 'category não informada';
      return $http.put(urlBase + '/' + category.Id, category)
    };

    dataFactory.deleteCategory = function (id) {
      if(id == null)
        throw 'Id não informado';
      return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + id);
    };

    dataFactory.getSubCategories = function (id) {
      if(id == null)
        throw 'Id não informado';
      return $http.get(urlBase + '/' + id + '/SubCategories');
    };

    return dataFactory;

  });
```

As you can see there is an "appConfig" service that I used to isolate API variables. Look at entire "services" folder at https://github.com/lazarofl/SPAwesome/tree/master/FrontEnd/app/scripts/services

In your controllers, you can reference each service that you want injecting service name on the controller constructor, like the code below.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name spawesomeApp.controller:CategoriesCtrl
 * @description
 * # CategoriesCtrl
 * Controller of the spawesomeApp
 */
 angular.module('spawesomeApp')
 .controller('CategoriesCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $log, $modal, Categories)
 {
    $scope.categories;
    $scope.alerts = [];
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.showadd = false;
    $scope.name = '';

    $scope.go = function ( path ) {
        $location.path( path );
    };

    $scope.addAlert = function(message, type) {
        $scope.alerts.push({type: type, msg: message});
    };

    $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.init = function(){
        $scope.loading = true;
        Categories
        .getCategories()
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.categories = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).
        error(function(error){
            $scope.addAlert('Não foi possível conectar na API, verifique a disponibilidade do serviço', 'danger');
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };

    $scope.editCategoryModal = function (index) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'editCategoryModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalEditCategoryCtrl',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                category: function () {
                    return $scope.categories[index];
                },
                name: function(){
                    return $scope.categories[index].Name;
                }
            }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (category) {
            $scope.addAlert('Categoria altera: "' + category.Name + '"','success');
        }, function () {

        });
    };

    $scope.addCategory = function(){
        $scope.loading = true;

        var category = {
            Name: $scope.name
        };

        Categories
        .insertCategory(category)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.init();

            $scope.addAlert($scope.name + ' adicionado com sucesso','success');
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.showadd = false;
        }).
        error(function(error){
            if(!!error)
                $scope.addAlert(error.ExceptionMessage, 'danger');
            else
                $scope.addAlert('Não foi possível adicionar a categoria, verifique a disponibilidade do serviço', 'danger');
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(index){

        if(confirm('Deseja realmente remover a categoria "' + $scope.categories[index].Name + '"?'))
        {

            $scope.loading = true;

            var toremove = $scope.categories[index];

            Categories
            .deleteCategory(toremove.Id)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.addAlert(toremove.Name + ' removida com sucesso','success');
                $scope.categories.splice(index, 1);
                $scope.loading = false;
            }).
            error(function(error){
                if(!!error)
                    $scope.addAlert(error.ExceptionMessage, 'danger');
                else
                    $scope.addAlert('Não foi possível remover a categoria, verifique a disponibilidade do serviço', 'danger');
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
        }

    };


 });
```

I hope this has helped

See ya.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$rootScope` to attach a function and access it from anywhere in your whole app but it is best to use service for this type of task

```
myApp.controller('ProposalController', ['$scope',  '$http', '$rootScope',function ($scope,  $http,$rootScope){
$rootScope.GetAddressByZipCode  = function GetAddressByZipCode(zipcode) {

$http.get('api/cep/consulta/' + zipcode)
     .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         if (data != null) {
             $scope.address = data.address;
             $scope.borough = data.borough.description;
             $scope.city = data.city.description;
             $scope.state = data.city.state.description;
         }
     })
     .error(function (data) {
         console.log("Error!");
     });
 }
}]);

myApp.controller('ContactController', ['$scope',  '$http','$rootScope' function ($scope,  $http,$rootScope){
 /*I need to invoke the GetAddressByZipCode(zipcode) here*/
 $rootScope.GetAddressByZipCode();
  }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be, use services instead polluting $rootScope. you can use factory to get data and re-use same function across your application

```
(function () {
'use strict';
  angular
.module("myApp")
.factory('getZipFactory', [
  '$scope',
  '$log',
  '$http',
  getZipFunction
]);

function getZipFunction($scope, $log, $http) {
return{
  getAddressByZipCode : function (zipCode) {
    $http.get('api/cep/consulta/' + zipcode)
      .success(function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
          return data
        }
      })
      .error(function (data) {
        console.log("Error!" + data);
      });
  }

}

}

}();
```

in your controller you can use something like

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .controller('ProposalController',[
            '$scope',
            '$log',
            'getZipFactory',
             ProposalControllerFunction
            ]);

     function ProposalControllerFunction($scope, $log, getZipFactory){

       $scope.myData = function (someZip ) {
          var promise = getZipFactory.getAddressByZipCode(someZip);
           promise.then(function (success) {
             $scope.myZipCode = success;
            });
       }

     }

   }());
```